# Не работает ввод русских букв в EditText в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

Добрый день!

Почему-то не работает ввод русских букв в EditText в Android Studio. Пробовала через стандартный эмулятор и Genimotion. Как только меняю раскладку - пишет на англ. нормально, на русском не пишет, даже в логах ничего нет.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае с Genymotion вам поможет включение в настройках эмулятора (в списке эмуляторов) использования виртуальной клавиатуры.

Answer (score 1):

В настройках Android в эмуляторе нужно выбрать русский язык.