# Android EditText ошибка при вводе символов русского алфавита

Tags: android

при вводе в editText русских символов, вводятся как будто их код. Как исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте представлено введенное "Мос"

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/select_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/select_city"
            android:imeActionId="6"
            android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
            android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: похоже на эмулятор. Проверяли на реальном устройстве?

Comment: Похоже да, но мне нужно тестировать, а так как база данных у меня находится на локальном сервере, то телефон не может получить доступ к БД. Как исправить эту проблему эмулятора? Эмулятор Genymotion

Comment: посмотрите http://www.cyberforum.ru/android-dev/thread1373435.html или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/406278/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2-%D0%B2-edittext-%D0%B2-android-studio

Comment: первую ссылку до этого просмотрел, включилась только английская виртуальная клавиатура

Comment: @Jarvis_J спасибо, жалко только что через клавиатуру компьютера нельзя вводить руссские символы

Comment: у меня на Генимошене все вводится (эмулирован custom phone 8, в настройки не лазил). Попробуйте обновить версию?

Comment: @Jarvis_J вы вводите с клавиатуры эмулятора или клавиатуры компьютера?

Comment: С компьютера...

Comment: @Jarvis_J странно, у меня русский вообще не вводится

Comment: @Jarvis_J вчера только поставил, куда обновляться

Comment: протестировал на другом виртуальной устройстве, в итоге русские символы вводятся, но краем глаза видно, что сначала вводятся код, и только потом он преобразуется в символы

Comment: И у меня так же

Comment: значит либо само виртуальное устройство либо версия SDK (я тестировал на 4.0.3)